# Subdomains on subdomain host route in Rails 3 -- hits route, not root

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, subdomain

Currently I have myapp.herokuapp.com as staging for a little project I'm working on. Once finished it'll be running under myapp.com.

When I'm running it locally, I'm using lvh.me:3000 to test things. This is working well for the problem I'm having, but since this staging environment is under a subdomain I'm having routing issues.

The problem is that my users are given a custom subdomain, thus, someuser.myapp.com points to users#landing. I accomplish this locally with this route:

```
  match '', to: 'users#landing', constraints: lambda { |r| r.subdomain.present? && r.subdomain != 'www' }
```

My issue is that when I visit myapp.herokuapp.com I end up hitting users#landing instead of my root.

I'm seriously drawing a blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Totally overlooked what I was doing...

I ended up,

```
if request.subdomain == 'myapp'
  redirect_to root_url
else
```

Which fixed the problem. I'm sure there's a better way to do this though.

Edit: furthermore, I added default_url_options in application_controller.rb

```
  def default_url_options
    if Rails.env.production?
      {:host => 'myapp.herokuapp.com'}
    else
      {:host => 'lvh.me'}
    end
  end
```